# Agrupamento de valores

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Possuo uma aplicação que gera os seguintes resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como posso organizar o objeto em apenas 1 linha, digamos ter apenas uma data, e dentro da data ter os horários, para ter apenas 1 linha para cada data.

Meu objeto é criado da seguinte forma:

```
namespace HBSIS.Models.WeatherViewModels
{
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public ResponseList[] list { get; set; }
    public ResponseCity city { get; set; }

}

public class ResponseCity
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseList
{
    public DateTime dt_txt { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    [JsonProperty("temp")]
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
}
}
```

Com o seguinte json:

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0066,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1560556800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 26.69,
            "temp_min": 26.69,
            "temp_max": 26.69,
            "pressure": 1012.35,
            "sea_level": 1012.35,
            "grnd_level": 782.51,
            "humidity": 19,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nuvens dispersas",
                "icon": "03n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 44
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.55,
            "deg": 307.139
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-15 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560567600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 16.48,
            "temp_min": 16.48,
            "temp_max": 16.48,
            "pressure": 1016.15,
            "sea_level": 1016.15,
            "grnd_level": 785.76,
            "humidity": 62,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 804,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nublado",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 100
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.65,
            "deg": 297.502
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-15 03:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560578400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 17.43,
            "temp_min": 17.43,
            "temp_max": 17.43,
            "pressure": 1015.73,
            "sea_level": 1015.73,
            "grnd_level": 784.88,
            "humidity": 52,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 804,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nublado",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 100
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.84,
            "deg": 229.68
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-15 06:00:00"
    }
]
}
```

E aqui está como estou recebendo ele hoje:

```
public async Task<WeatherForecast> GetCityWeatherAsync(string city)
    {
        string _apiKey = _configuration["API_Access_Weather:AccessKey"];

        string _urlBase = _configuration["API_Access_Weather:UrlBase"];

        try
        {
            using (var standings = new HttpClient())
            {
                var path = _urlBase + "q=" + city + "&units=metric&lang=pt&APPID=" + _apiKey;

                standings.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                standings.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage respToken = await standings.GetAsync(path);

                WeatherForecast _weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast();

                if (respToken.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string content = respToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    _weatherForecast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherForecast>(content);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(respToken.StatusCode.ToString() + " - " + respToken.ReasonPhrase);

                return _weatherForecast;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Algo deu errado ao tentar buscar o clima da cidade :'{city}' e a exceção foi lançada: '{ex}' ");
        }
    }
```

Através desse objeto gostaria de criar um novo +- dessa forma:

```
2019-06-15 {
00: 19
03: 18
06: 15
09: 22
....
}
```

Me indicaram fazer um DTO, mas não sei como posso fazer isso, já tentei até com `LINQ`, mas nao sei como agrupar os valores que recebo do array, descrito acima.

Oque consegui fazer até agora é agrupar uma parte, mas não exatamente como quero:

```
var retorno = _weatherForecast.list
                                  .GroupBy(y => y.dt_txt.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))
                                  .Select(x => new
                                  {
                                      date = x.FirstOrDefault().dt_txt.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"),
                                      hour = x.Select(y => y.dt_txt.Hour).ToList(),
                                      temp = x.Select(y => y.main.Temperature).ToList()
                                  });
```

Comment: mostre como você tentou gerar o resultado que espera

Comment: @Leandro Angelo, está falando da tabela ? Que eu gerei da forma errada ?

Comment: Já tentou fazer um DTO para este endpoint?

Comment: Isso que estou querendo fazer amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um pouco complexo de entender o seu negócio em si, porém o que você quer é fazer um retorno com *referência cruzada* de informações.

Para isso você deve ter um model que se adapte a essa idéia, por exemplo:

```
 public class ConsultaTempoModel()
 {
     public DateTime Data { get; set; }
     public List<int, double> TemperaturaPorHora {get; set;} //----- Considerando aqui que a hora é um inteiro e a temperatura é um double
 }
```

A questão agora é você preencher uma lista desse modelo `List<ConsultaTempoModel>`.

Depois de preenchido você consegue montar uma construção que o exiba na tela.

Como se trata de um caso específico não sei se consegui te ajudar de alguma forma, espero que sim. Abraço

Comment: Acredito que o que ele deseja fazer é um groupby através da Data, não?